# Haskell file I/O return types not matching?

Tags: haskell

Forward notice, this is my first day of Haskell.

So I have a function `parse :: String -> String`, I'm attempting to pass a file to it as such, either through the standard,

```
input <- readFile "input.txt"
```

or the other standard,

```
handle <- openFile "input.txt" ReadMode
input <- hGetContents handle
```

To which I want to perform,

```
output <- unlines $ map parse $ lines input
```

(Or however that should be canonically formatted)
Now as I understand it, readFile returns a string, lines takes a string and returns a list of strings, and map should map over a list of strings. If this is true, then why is `lines input` telling me that got a [String] instead of a String, while omitting `lines` and just having `map parse input` tells me it got a String instead of a [String]?

Comment: *"readFile returns a string"*. No, [it doesn't](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:readFile).

Comment: @MarkSeemann Well, the _function_ doesn't return a string, but it "returns" a string in the `IO` metaphor sense.

Comment: You don't seem to understand the way monads and `do`-notation works.  Might I suggest reading [the relevent LYAH chapter?](http://learnyouahaskell.com/a-fistful-of-monads)

Comment: @AJFarmar They claim this is their first day of Haskell. I'd be shocked if they knew how Monads and the do notation work.

Comment: The [LYAH IO chapter](http://learnyouahaskell.com/input-and-output) might be more useful.

Comment: @Cubic you're right, I didn't see that at first. It would be best simply to read LYAH from the start.

Comment: @AJFarmar Oh, I have. Almost twice at the time of this writing. I'm hopelessly lost with monads, but I'm getting there. It all just sounds pretty complicated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is the working example

```
parse :: String -> String
parse = id -- don't do anything to input

main = do
    input <- readFile "input.txt"
    let output = unlines $ map parse $ lines input
    print output
```

In your example everything is fine except for `output <-` which should be replaced with the `let output =` for a reason you probably don't get yet, judging on your wording: `readFile` returns a string. As it was pointed in the comments, it is not. It returns `IO String` which means an IO-action you may fire up and get a string (or not… if, say, a file does not exist). The `<-` operation lets you inspect positive outcome of this action: it says that when the action is successful, you get a string (which you called `input`). And then you can play with it.

So why is `<-` not appropriate in the second line (with `lines`, `map` and stuff)? Simply because there is no action in it. You are applying *pure functions* in there. Binding a result of pure computations is done via `let smth =`.

Also, please, be aware that `<-` as well as `let X =` belong to do-blocks, syntactic constructs designed to write a sequence of steps to process actions. In contrast, inside pure functions you can find `let X = … in` (note `in`) or `where X =` to bind intermediate results.

Comment: Worth pointing out that this syntax is _only_ valid in `do` blocks (and ghci) - everywhere else it is `let x = ... in`

Comment: Heeey, there it is. Thank you. I suppose I never made the connection with the do-block.